# drag and drop on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, drag-and-drop

I'm new to android. I would appreciate if somebody could write the most basic code that implements drag and drop of a textview over an imageview. or more specific draging a letter to an dashed line frame that sets the letter into the frame on drop.

I lfound lots of examples on the net but non work properly and most of them are outdated.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_drag_and_drop.htm

Comment: Tried that. the draggable just disappears on drop.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this recently using following link. Hope it will help you too.
This is the easy way to drag and drop views in android without using any external library

[link](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.z4zak6pci)

Answer (score 0):

```
Noam, I think you should just check out the xml file and edit the code without draging and dropping

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@String/textOnImage">

</ImageView>
```

Comment: Noam wants to drag and drop views at real time.. so this won't work.

Comment: Oh, then you'll need quite a number of touch and slide listeners

Comment: Try out something first, then people will be ready to help. If we ain't seeing anything, there'll be no motivation to help. Give it a try first